# How to vectorize categorical data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I would like to vectorize some categorical data in order to build a train and test matrix.

I have 85 cities and I would like to get a matrix with 282520 rows, every row being a vector like

```
[1 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
```

I would like to have a vector per row with 1 or 0 depending of the city, so consequently every city should be a column:

```
print(df['city'])
```

```
0         METROPOLITANA DE SANTIAGO
1         METROPOLITANA DE SANTIAGO
2         METROPOLITANA DE SANTIAGO
3         METROPOLITANA DE SANTIAGO
4                          COQUIMBO
5                          SANTIAGO
6                          SANTIAGO
7         METROPOLITANA DE SANTIAGO
8         METROPOLITANA DE SANTIAGO
9         METROPOLITANA DE SANTIAGO
10                          BIO BIO
11                         COQUIMBO
...                             ...
282520    METROPOLITANA DE SANTIAGO
Name: city, dtype: object
```

This is what I tried:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

list_city = getList(df,'city')
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(list_city)

print(le.transform(['AISEN'])) 
print(le.transform(['TARAPACA']))
print(le.transform(['AISEN DEL GENERAL CARLOS IBANEZ DEL CAMP']))
```

I am getting the following output:

```
[0]
[63]
[1]
```

The problem is that I am just getting the index of the city, I am looking for suggestions how to vectorize the data.

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for the [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder)? That sounds more like what you're looking for to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option is `pd.get_dummies` (which is completely outside the `sklearn` ecosystem).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['METROPOLITANA DE SANTIAGO', 'COQUIMBO', 'SANTIAGO', 'SANTIAGO'],
                  columns=['city'])
pd.get_dummies(df)
```

```
   city_COQUIMBO  city_METROPOLITANA DE SANTIAGO  city_SANTIAGO
0              0                               1              0
1              1                               0              0
2              0                               0              1
3              0                               0              1
```

If you need a NumPy array, just grab the `values`.

```
pd.get_dummies(df).values
```

```
[[0 1 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 0 1]]
```

---

Another approach is to use a combination of `LabelEncoder` and `OneHotEncoder`. As you noticed, `LabelEncoder` will return categorical indices for an array of arbitrary labels. `OneHotEncoder` will flip these indices into a one-of-k encoding scheme.

```
le = LabelEncoder()
enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
enc.fit_transform(le.fit_transform(df.city.values).reshape(-1, 1))
```

```
[[ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]]
```

---

Yet another option is `DictVectorizer`.

```
dv = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
dv.fit_transform(df.apply(dict, 1))
```

```
[[ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]]
```

Comment: thanks for the support this is very helpul however, this is going to give me 85 columns, then I will need to find a way to convert this 85 columns in a numpy array to build a matrix

Comment: @neo I edited my answer to show how to extract an `ndarray` from the result of `pd.get_dummies`, as well as two more approaches.

Comment: @thanks for the help, I really appreciate the support,  thanks a lot